# Start multiple nodes at boot and give access to ports

Tags: ros, roslaunch, ros-indigo, startup

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently when testing our robot (Ubuntu 14.04, ROS indigo), we need to start lots of nodes by hand. This takes lots of time when doing this over and over. Therefore we've tried to write a startup script using a bash script. But then when it started roscore, it does not execute all the other commands. Bassically what we are trying to do is automate the following terminal commands. For example, now only the startup of the xsens was used. But, like this, we need to start a laserscanner, a logitech controller, a camera and motorcontrollers as well. We found out we can do it using a launch file, but we do not now how to give permission to read a port that way. Does anyone have tips regarding this topic on how to automate the next process: ?

On startup:

New terminal:

```
$ roscore
```

New terminal:

```
$ cd /bullseye/catkin_ws/
$ source devel/setup.bash
$ sudo chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
$ rosrun xsens_driver mtdevice.py -f 5
$ rosrun xsens_driver mtnode.py
```

New terminal:

```
$ cd test_bullseye/
$ python xsens.py
```

Thanks in advance,
Sander

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206987/start-multiple-nodes-at-boot-and-give-access-to-ports/) by [Sander](https://answers.ros.org/users/21998/sander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-04-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are addressing three different problems.
First is system startup: To set permissions the clean way would be udev - rules. The quick way is change */etc/rc.local*

```
#!/bin/sh -e
# ... bla bla
# By default this script does nothing.
chmod a+rw /dev/ttyUSB0
exit 0
```

The next point is starting your ros nodes: take a look at the [roslaunch](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch) documentation.

And the last is start problem of your application on desktop level: I would create a bash script which starts two terminals (I suggest xterm, because it is quite easily scriptable) which automatically start roslaunch and another terminal with the python script. Depending on your desktop environment you can call the script at startup of the graphical system.

---

Originally posted by [georg l](https://answers.ros.org/users/22092/georg-l/) with karma: 186 on 2015-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2